# HTML5 Video Playback issue in Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, html5-video, playback

I need some help.

I have this site [here](http://sailingroundtheisland.williamchanter.co.uk/) and if you look at it in Chrome, then the video fits the screen, yet in Safari it does not fit :(

This is the issue? I want it to fit !!!

This is the html 5 video code...

```
<video id="top" class="video" width="100%" height="100%" poster="te/wave.jpg" preload="auto" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" >
    <source src="te/wave.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="te/wave.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Any help would be good

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to tell a video to explicitly ignore the aspect ratio, but try adding this as CSS. It may work...

```
<style>
video { 
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(2); 
  -moz-transform: scaleX(2);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but then it distorts the video in all browsers, which doesn't look great. Is there a way to mimic what chrome does automatically in safari?

Comment: Cool, sorry it doesn't work the way you want. To answer your qyestion: No, I don't think so. As I say, there's no way to tell the browser to ignore the aspect ratio. Safari thinks it's being helpful by maintaining it for you. Flash video would stretch no problem, I think.